# Java - creating list in JList from a String array

Tags: java, jlist

I am creating a small program using NetBeans, and I want to be able to display the contents of a String array in a JList. I have created a JList in a JPanel by using NetBeans' design view and dragging the JList option into the JPanel from the list of swing controls.

The JList is named listbox, and I am trying to populate it from a String array called routeList. My code is:

```
void startup(){
        routeList[0]="Julie";
        routeList[1]="Helen";
        routeList[2]="Sophie";
        routeList[3]="Lizzie";
        routeList[4]="Maria";
        routeList[5]="Angela";

        DefaultListModel<String> mmodel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
            mmodel.addElement(routeList[x]);        
        }
        listbox.setModel(mmodel);
        listbox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```

The code runs OK, and I know that the method startup is being executed, but nothing happens - the JList box on the screen remains blank.

This is the first time I have ever tried to use JList. I have found a lot of stuff about it on the web, but most of it suggests code just like this and I can't work out what I am doing wrong. Could it be something to do with the  model  property in the JList properties?

Can someone tell me what is wrong, or tell me what code I should be using, please.

Comment: You should look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question here after 2 days searching!:
    http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/mpenderg/ism3230Notes/jlist.html

Following the advice there, I did the following:

1. In the design tab, create a JList by dragging from the swing controls box into a JPanel. Right click the JList box, select  Change Variable Name, and name the box something meaningful (I called mine  listbox )
2. In the Properties box in design tab, click the button against "model". A "model options" pane appears. Choose "Custom code" in the drop down box at the top, and type

   new DefaultListModel()

   in the "listbox.setModel" box.
3. I had already defined and populated a 10 element String array called routeList[]. After initComponents I added the following code:

`DefaultListModel routesmodel = (DefaultListModel)listbox.getModel();
        for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
            routesmodel.addElement(routeList[x]);
        }`

It then worked - I got a scrollable JList box populated with data!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code generated by NetBeans:

```
    jList.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
```